# How can I prevent this model to learn more(less) :)))

Tags: python, overfitting, boosting

As you can see, GradientBoostingClassifier overfit with more training example.
These are my parameter for the model:

{'learning_rate': 0.1, 'loss': 'deviance', 'max_depth': 6, 'max_features': 0.3, 'min_samples_leaf': 80, 'n_estimators': 300}

What should I to make my model better or stop training at 350?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well, by making your model *better*, I suppose you mean enforcing some sort of regularization on it, so that it doesn't overfit. Early stopping, however can be viewed as a regularization method by itself.

I would suggest sampling the performance of your model more frequently (than the 200 examples you are doing currently) and if you see the validation score is not improving after a few iterations stop the training.

Early stopping can be implemented through the `monitor` parameter in the GradientBoostingClassifier's `.fit()` method.

Comment: How I should add regularization to a GradientBoostingClassifier? I thought regularization reduce the complexity of a model, how it help here?